# Change SQL Server encryption algorithm

Tags: sql-server

I do not want admin to be able to view the source code. I could use

> Create stored procedure ... with encryption

But it can easily be decrypted (just google)

To protect stored procedure source code, I want to override the encryption algorithm. Is there a way to do this? (like SQLShield http://www.sqlshield.com/). Or you can suggest me how to encrypt and decrypt stored procedure by CLR.

Comment: That's the wrong question. The correct question is, *why* do you want to *obfuscate* the stored procedure in the first place? Obfuscation is *not* a security feature. Besides, if the stored procedure contains enough code that it needs "protecting", it's already too bloated to be a good stored procedure. If it contains sensitive data, eg keys, it's probably a bad design. SQL Server does offer strong data encryption, even using Key vault services in SQL Server 2016

Comment: And asymmetric encryption with certificates in all previous versions

Comment: Can you tell me how SQLShield work?

Comment: If you can't trust your database administrators, you have a *people* problem, not a *technical* one.

Comment: @Dat I can tell you its weaker than the built-in asymmetric encryption

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever not quite, which is why there are auditing and encryption services in the first place. Thinking your customer will steal your stored procedures though ... I can't think of a stored procedure *worth copying* that isn't already available in one or another blog post by the usual suspects like Aaron Bertrand, Brent Ozar, Itzik Ben Gan etc. In fact, it it isn't one of *theirs*, it isn't worth copying

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My partner company is admin. I sell product, but no source code

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I encrypt to protect source code. If I use built-in asymmetric encryption, I need a password to encrypt and decrypt. So they can see this password and use it to decrypt

Comment: The only approaches that actually work to protect your IP are a) don't put it on other people's servers or b) rely on contract law, copyright law and similar legal protections (i.e. if someone else rips of your code, you sue them). Those approaches work. Anything else, where somehow someone else's machine has to be able to read and understand your code whilst at the same time is incapable of reading and understanding your code doesn't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I encrypt source code, and decrypt it before execute

Comment: And for that to work, the decryption key has to be available.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes. But "Create stored procedure ... with encryption" don't need a key, SQLShield too

Answer (score 1):

The **WITH ENCRYPTION** clause of CREATE PROCEDURE is an old legacy option that only obfuscates the code. This is stated in the official documentation: "Indicates that SQL Server converts the original text of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement to an obfuscated format."

At the moment (2019), there is no SQL Server feature that can achieve what you seek. The database system administrator will be able to access the code of any procedure that you create on their server. Especially if they also happen to be an administrator of the server machine as well, as is often the case. If the database is not encrypted, it is as simple as opening the MDF file in notepad to see the code of all its stored procedures - try it out!

Usually, this question comes from people that want to sell a SQL Server package of procedures, but do not want to give access to their code. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to achieve this type of code protection when your client owns the hardware on which the server runs - what you are looking for is a digital rights management type of solution.

You might want to look instead at packaging your application as a service, if you want better control over your application.

That being said, future versions of SQL Server may add features that may help with this scenario - especially in hosted SQL Server scenarios.